# weblogic deployment InternalException : Transaction marked rollback or not expected transaction

Tags: java, transactions, ejb, weblogic

I have an EAR application, and when i try to deploy it to my weblogic server, i get the following error:

```
<[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1439994186702> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.ejb.container.InternalException: Transaction marked rollback or not expected transaction status: 1
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused By: weblogic.ejb.container.InternalException: Transaction marked rollback or not expected transaction status: 1
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager.handleLifecycleCallbackTx(SingletonSessionManager.java:422)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager.constructAndInitBean(SingletonSessionManager.java:339)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager.access$300(SingletonSessionManager.java:62)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager$SingletonLifecycleManager.doActualInit(SingletonSessionManager.java:753)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager$SingletonLifecycleManager.initInternal(SingletonSessionManager.java:701)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager$SingletonLifecycleManager.init(SingletonSessionManager.java:588)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager.init(SingletonSessionManager.java:255)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager.perhapsInit(SingletonSessionManager.java:251)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.start(EJBDeployer.java:968)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.start(EJBModule.java:597)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
>
```

I have a `@Singleton` in my application, but it doesn't seem that the problem is there since it's not raised from there.

I looked for in the internet for the same problem, but all the given solutions were not enough for me.

Any help?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

By restarting my local machine (on which the weblogic server was installed), the deployment produced more detailed error info, as it was something like this

```
javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: Singleton MySingleton(Application:MYEAR-3.0.1_C1, EJBComponent: MYEJB.jar) failed to initialize.
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: EJB Exception: 
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [MyPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [MyPU] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select o from Transaction o where o.internalId = :internalId and (o.validUntil is nullor CURRENT_TIMESTAMP between o.validFrom and o.validUntil)]. 
[30, 139] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
[139, 140] The query contains a malformed ending.
```

It seems that my issue was an error in a `@NamedQuery`, so i solved it, but i'll leave this question open, as this doesn't answer it: How can someone tell what an `weblogic.ejb.container.InternalException` is?

Answer (score 0):

You can know the type and details of the exception by looking at the server logs which is is AdminServer/logs in your domain directory, it will give you details and description of the exceptions and what happened with the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I am just writing down my own case with encountering a similar error while deploying an EAR-packaged application into `Weblogic 12.1.3`.

What I think happened to me is that there was another error hidden somewhere early in the initialization process, which I wasn't spotting because of very verbose logging.

Apparently there were some breaking changes in my code, the JPA layer was trying to read some constants from the database during the initialization (there is still some code out there that would trap those errors and hide them from you) and was failing - as the result `EJB` layer wasn't initialized properly, and the obscure exception with the rollback was issued afterwards. So this wasn't exactly having to do with the deployment process, but with the initialization of the application itself.

**EDIT:** to double-check this - if the logs do not show something that would make sense, try restarting Weblogic to better see the initialization process